# is there a way to apply condition on multiple attributes in rails serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I would like to know if there is an easier way to apply any condition on a serializer with multiple attributes (sorry in advance if am not clear enough) for example:

```
class AbcSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :a, :b, :c, if: :condition?

  def condition?
    true
  end
end
```

This should get all a, b and c according to conditon

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it:

```
class AbcSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :a, :b, :c

  def attributes(*args)
    hash = super
    hash.delete_if { |k, _| %i[a b c].include? k } unless condition?
    hash
  end

  def condition?
    true
  end
end
```

I haven't tested it but should work with/without minor changes.